# Junit Test for a program to remove duplicates in a string array

Tags: java, junit

I am new to Java & Junit testing. My question is, how to fix the error I am getting with the following Junit test code. The Java code returns the desired output when checked with a print statement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Junit test code

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RemoveDuplicateTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        RemoveDuplicatesStringArray rd = new RemoveDuplicatesStringArray();

        String[] strArray = {"ellen","talk","show","ellen","talk","show","ellen","talk"};
        rd.removeDups(strArray);

        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("show","ellen","talk"),strArray.toString());
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RemoveDuplicatesStringArray {

    public List<String> removeDups(String[] str){
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < str.length; j++){
                if(str[i].equals(str[j])){
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            if(count < 1){
                strList.add(str[i]);
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < strList.size(); ){
            System.out.println("check "+strList);
            System.out.println(strList.getClass());
            return(strList);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What's wrong with `new HashSet(Arrays.asList(str))`? Also what's _with_ the `for` loop with the `return` statement??

Comment: How can you compare `Arrays.asList(...)` which returns a list with a `String`?

Comment: Also, how on earth can `Arrays.asList("show","ellen","talk")` be `equals` to `strArray.toString()`?? Sorry - but what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe that is not directly related to question, but you can remove duplicates by just converting list of strings to set like this: `Set<String> removedDups = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(strArray))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question, your test has a couple of errors:

```
    String[] strArray = {"ellen","talk","show","ellen","talk","show","ellen","talk"};
    rd.removeDups(strArray);
```

`removeDups` leaves the passed array unchanged and you ignore the result that should be the list containing only the unique elements.

```
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("show","ellen","talk"),strArray.toString());
```

Here you compare a list with the string representation of a String array. This will never be evaluated as equal. Even if you change it to

```
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("show","ellen","talk").tostring(), Arrays.asList(strArray).toString());
```

you still compare the complete array with all duplicate values with the one with unique values leading to the same result.

I suppose you wanted to do the foll

```
public void test() {

    RemoveDuplicatesStringArray rd = new RemoveDuplicatesStringArray();

    String[] strArray = {"ellen","talk","show","ellen","talk","show","ellen","talk"};
    List<String> checkList = rd.removeDups(strArray);

    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("ellen","talk","show").tostring(),checkList.toString());
}
```

I changed the order of the values in the list containing the expected values because the values are added to the resulting list in the order they appear in the source list the first time. Otherwise your check will still be negative.

BTW: `removeDups` is a performance hell. As mentioned in the comments, using `HashSet` or similar classes are much better because they are

1. Already available, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel
2. Much faster because they don't iterate over the whole target list for each input-element

Comment: doubt this does anything useful... `assertEquals(Arrays.asList("ellen","talk","show"),checkList.toString())`

Comment: Thank you kindly for your time & help. I have a better understanding now with your explanation. I had something similar to your solution but didn't use List. I will definitely consider the other suggested solutions.

Comment: @Lothar solution works with a minor addition assertEquals(Arrays.asList("show","ellen","talk").toString(),checkList.toString());

Comment: @BoristheSpider I forgot to add again the `toString`. Fixed that, thanks.

Comment: That's even more horrible now. Why would you compare the `String` representation of collections? What is wrong with `assertEquals(Arrays.asList("ellen","talk","show"),checkList)`? Or even, in a sane world, `assertThat(checkList, containsExactly("ellen","talk","show"))` so you get sensible test output.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's not horrible. I use this quite often because - at least with Eclipse - a failed test of assertEquals(String, String) opens a dialog if you double-click the line with the error message showing a diff of the expected and the actual string. This makes it very easy to see where exactly the two strings differ. The two examples you provided don't do that taking more time to find out where things do fail.

Comment: What makes you think that the `toString` of a random `List` implementation would always be exactly the same as the implementation of `Arrays.ArrayList`? I prefer my tests not to randomly fail because of changes to the `toString` methods of unrelated classes. The fact the people do this on a regular basis makes me cry; and the fact that people write code to make it easier for their IDE makes me despair for the state of software engineering. Lastly, **any** sensible IDE will do this regardless of whether you give the `List` or a `String` because comparing collections in tests is very common.

Comment: @BoristheSpider https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--

Comment: But I return a `DeDuplicatedList` from the `removeDuplicates` method that doesn't inherit from `AbstractList`? How does linked to documentation for arbitrary implementations prove anything? You have a `List`, so the only assumptions you can make are about _that_ `interface`.

Comment: And the documentation you linked is for a type that doesn't even inherit from `List`...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Last comment from me about this: This question doesn't contain your code and the code I write unit tests for, either. I used this technique to put together multiple values to test into a single string to compare that against an expected text for nearly 20 years now and never got a problem with that. If you don't like this way of testing, that's OK but that doesn't make it horrible or wrong.

Comment: It's absolutely wrong. Whether you think that things are wrong are horrible I suppose is a question. But I think things that look right and sort of work but then break _horrible_. Comparing equality of objects by their string representation is definitely wrong however.